# How to use Docker along with Oracle Virtual Box?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, docker

Docker [requires Hyper-V to be turned ON](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#hyper-v), while Oracle Virtual Box requires Hyper-V to be turned OFF.

So it is impossible to use both Docker and Oracle Virtual Box on the same Windows machine or there is a workaround?

I found there is [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/), but it is said it is for "old machines". My machine is definitely not old. What is it? Blaming user with vendor software incompatibilities? Is it normal to use Docker Toolbox on modern machine?

Comment: To my knowledge its impossible. But Everything you can do with VirtualBox can be done with Hyper-V too. Why not simply switch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269375/470749 might be a good suggestion.

Comment: @LPChip if `A` and `B` have the same functionality, what was the purpose to make system-wide switch to disabling one of them? Is this a case of unfair competition?

Comment: @Dims Hyper-V can do everything VirtualBox can do, but VirtualBox cannot host a Docker container. So the reason to switch is, so you can do both VM's and Docker at the same time.

Comment: The reason you cannot use both, is because of direct access to a hardware function called VT-x. It is accessed at boot, and as such, if Hyper-V uses it, Oracle VM cannot, and visa versa.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with Docker Toolbox/Docker Machine.